# Ansible: print elements from joined list of dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, ansible

I am trying to access elements from both lists: lista1 and lista2.
First join them into one dictionary and then to be able to do something like this:

```
Vegetable {{ lista1.fruits.name }} has taste {{ lista1.fruits.taste }}
```

This is what I got so far, but it's really bad,and I would like to have dictionary like access instead of regex_search.

```
---
- name: demo how register works
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    lista1:
     fruits:
      - name: tomato
        taste: tomato-like
      - name: lemon
        taste: sour
    lista2:
     vegetables:
      - name: carrot
        taste: sweet
  tasks:
   - name: debug 
     debug:
        var: item
     loop:
        - lista1.fruits
        - lista2.vegetables
     register: echo
   - name: show register results
     debug:
         msg: "Food named: {{ item| map(attribute='name')|list|join(', ') |regex_search('tomato') }} tastes: {{ item| map(attribute='taste')|list|join(', ')|regex_search('tomato-like') }}"
     loop: "{{ lista1.fruits|zip(lista2.vegetables)|list }} "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `debug` task to show the "food" with its "taste" can be displayed by accessing `item.name` and `item.taste` by looping through `lista1.fruits` and `lista2.vegetables`.

Example:

```yaml
    - name: show register results
      debug:
        msg: "Food named: {{ item.name }} tastes: {{ item.taste }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ lista1.fruits }}"
        - "{{ lista2.vegetables }}"
```

---

*Update*

Instead of `with_items`, `loop` can be used as:

```yaml
    - name: show register results
      debug:
        msg: "Food named: {{ item.name }} tastes: {{ item.taste }}"
      loop: "{{ lista1.fruits + lista2.vegetables }}"
```

Comment: Thanks, I focused to much on loop statement here.

Comment: This can be done using `loop` as well, but using `+` instead of `zip`. Like `{{ lista1.fruits + lista2.vegetables }}`. Will update my answer as an option.